# RNBLueModalView throws lldb error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm using [RNBLueModalView](https://github.com/rnystrom/RNBlurModalView) for presenting new modal view with following code:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    smallStoreViewController *Store = [[smallStoreViewController alloc]init];

    Store = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"small store"];

    RNBlurModalView *mod = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithViewController:self view:Store.view];

    [mod show];
```

There's six buttons in smallStoreViewController view, but when i pressed at any of them i'm getting lldb exception - *(button name)* unrecognized selector sent to instance. Everything is working fine when i use [default](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/presentedViewController)(`presentedViewController` method) presenting of modal view. This is pretty strange behaviour, because i'm used this approach in my previous project, and all was working fine.

**Any advice of where i can find the reason of this exception?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i find the solution:
I should've keep the strong reference of my `smallStoreViewController`. I guess error happening because of assigning it to `Store` as a local variable, and it's not around when button of modal view is pressed. (The error shows that  memory has been released and re-used for a different type of object.)

Comment: Could you walk me through your solution? I have a Login viewcontroller A that allocs and inits *loginController. RNBlurModal get it and shows it (without the x). I have a cancel and OK button in the view. But the view isn't active once it's shown. How do I get around it? How do I keep a strong reference to *loginController?